# Can I use a schema constraint to enforce uniqueness with a twist?

Tags: sql, constraints

Let's say I have two related entities, eg. a project and a filter. A filter can be either:

- shared, ie. it's available to all projects
- private, ie. it is limited to just one project

Each filter can be given a name and I want to ensure that filters have unique names. However uniqueness is dependent on whether the filter is shared or private. If a filter is shared, its name must be unique across all shared filters *and* no private filter can re-use the name. If a filter is private, then it must be unique *within its project*, ie. two different projects can have two private filters with the same name.

I am going to store the filter data in a database table and I'd like to add a constraint to enforce these naming rules. Is it possible to construct a composite key to do this?

I'm imagining two columns on the filter table:

- the filter's name (string)
- a project ID (numeric, ideally a foreign key to the project table)

A shared filter will have a name and no project ID, while a private filter will have a name and the ID of the project it belongs to.

Can I construct a constraint to enforce this?

Any thoughts on my approach? Am I on the right track or is there a better way?

Comment: A composite primary key works for you?

Comment: I don't know - at this stage I'm still designing, so I'm after feedback on my design (as opposed to code).

Comment: AFAIK, if you use a composite key, all the fields are compared as if they were one key, so I think you could use it. But I think that is not recommended...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I actually have to support multiple DBs, eg. PostgreSQL, MySQL, MSSQL and so on. Are constraints always DB specific?

Comment: Constraints are in standard SQL, but there's no guarantee all brands support the semantics of standard SQL the same, or in compatible ways. Trying to develop simple code that supports many RDBMS implementations the same is pretty much impossible.

Comment: I understand. Do you think a constraint is possible, even if it has to be DB specific?

Comment: The `shared` column isn't actually needed in your design. Because it carries the same information as the `project_id` column

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want using only constraints.

I was able to design this table:

```
create table filters (
        filter_id int auto_increment primary key,
        filter_name varchar(20) not null,
        project_id int,
        is_shared bool as (case when project_id is null then true else null end),
        unique key (filter_name, project_id),
        unique key (filter_name, is_shared)
);
```

This enforces the constraints that shared filters must be unique, and private filters must be unique among other filters of the same project.

I.e. the following filters succeed:

```
insert into filters set filter_name = 'shared1', project_id = null; -- OK
insert into filters set filter_name = 'shared2', project_id = null; -- OK
insert into filters set filter_name = 'private1', project_id = 1;   -- OK
insert into filters set filter_name = 'private2', project_id = 1;   -- OK
insert into filters set filter_name = 'private1', project_id = 2;   -- OK
insert into filters set filter_name = 'private2', project_id = 2;   -- OK
```

But these fail, correctly:

```
insert into filters set filter_name = 'shared1', project_id = null; -- DUPLICATE
insert into filters set filter_name = 'private1', project_id = 1;   -- DUPLICATE
insert into filters set filter_name = 'private1', project_id = 2;   -- DUPLICATE
```

However, the tricky part that I can't solve is to make private filter names conflict with shared filter names, but not with private filter names from different projects.

```
insert into filters set filter_name = 'shared1', project_id = 1;
insert into filters set filter_name = 'private1', project_id = null;
```

We can't just make filter_name UNIQUE, because that would make private filters from different projects conflict with each other.

```
unique key (filter_name) -- WRONG
```

I also looked into creating a [VIEW WITH CHECK OPTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-check-option.html), but it would require using a self-join or NOT EXISTS subquery, and both of those cases mean the view doesn't support WITH CHECK OPTION.

I was able to do this with a trigger in MySQL 5.7:

```
delimiter //
create trigger it1 before insert on filters
for each row begin
  if exists (select * from filters as f2 where f2.filter_name = NEW.filter_name and f2.project_id is null) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' 
    set message_text = 'filter conflicts with an existing shared filter';
  end if;
  if exists (select * from filters as f2 where f2.filter_name = NEW.filter_name and NEW.project_id is null) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' 
    set message_text = 'filter conflicts with an existing private filter';
  end if;
  if exists (select * from filters as f2 where f2.filter_name = NEW.filter_name and f2.project_id = NEW.project_id) then
    signal sqlstate '45000' 
    set message_text = 'filter conflicts with an existing private filter in the same project';
  end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```